# HOW to SUM same values of rows I have a table PURCHASE_ITEM :

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

```
"SELECT productID, qty, bill_date 
FROM purchase_item 
WHERE supplierID = 5 
GROUP BY purchase_itemID"


**1 400 2015-06-01
  2 100 2015-06-01
  3 200 2015-06-01
  5 150 2015-06-01
  2 110 2015-06-01   **
```

How i sum qty only of common productID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM` function as

```
"Select SUM ('qty') as totalQty FROM purchase_item 
 WHERE supplierID = 5 
 GROUP BY purchase_itemID"
```

Comment: i want to add 100 and 110 (qty) of same productID (which is 2)

Comment: then try this select productID, sum(qty)
FROM purchase_item WHERE supplierID = 5
group by productID